# Is there a way to tell routing that my default action name is equal to the HTTP Action Verb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've looked through [this document](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) on MSDN and can't come up with the answer.

Considering that I have a route defined like this:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultWithActionAndID",
        routeTemplate: "v{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: new {
            action = @"[a-zA-Z]+",
            id = @"\d+"
        }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultWithID",
        routeTemplate: "v{version}/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: new {
            id = @"\d+"
        }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultWithoutActionOrId",
        routeTemplate: "v{version}/{controller}",
        defaults: null,
    );
```

Now I have two controllers that looks like this:

```
public class ItemController:ApiController{
    [HttpGet]
    public Item Get(int id){}

    [HttpGet]
    public Item GetSomething(int id){}

    [HttpPut]
    public Item Put(Item newItem){}
}

public class AnotherController:ApiController{
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(Something item){}
}
```

I'd like to be able to call all of these endpoints like this:

```
GET /api/Item/344
GET /api/Item?id=344
GET /api/Item/Something/2334
GET /api/Item/Something?id=2334
PUT /api/Item     body={newItem}
PUT /api/Another  body={newSomething}
```

This will work, but only if I add "Get" as the default action name. If I do not specify a default action name in my route, then it complains about multiple matching action names. If I do add the default action name, then I cannot call PUT to the Put() method without an error because the action name doesn't match the default and isn't found.

```
    // Will work in some cases, but not all
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultWithID",
        routeTemplate: "v{version}/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {
            action="Get",
            id=RouteParameters.Optional
        },
        constraints: new {
            id = @"\d+"
        }
    );

    // Works
GET /api/Item/344
GET /api/Item?id=344
GET /api/Item/Something/2334
GET /api/Item/Something?id=2334

// Doesn't work
PUT /api/Item     body={newItem}
PUT /api/Another  body={newSomething}
```

How can I tell Routing to use the Action with the name that matches my HTTP Verb, if one exists before trying to use

Comment: Please include the code for "If I do add the default action name...".

Comment: Why not put `Something` in another controller?

Comment: Updated the question with more details of failing cases. The problem seems to be that routing doesn't have an extra level of priority (looking for method names that match the HTTP Verb or `{verb}{controller}` pattern like MVC does). Actually, a `{verb}` token would be quite a nice addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your routes as follows:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultWithActionAndID",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new {action = @"[a-zA-Z]+", id = @"\d*" }
            );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultWithID",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "GET", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { id = @"\d*", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }) }
        );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultWithoutActionOrId",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
        defaults: new { action = "PUT" },
        constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "PUT" }) }
        );
```

And also place the `ActionName` attribute on your GetSomething method as so:

```
[ActionName("Something")]
public Item GetSomething(int id){}
```

You should then be able to hit all the endpoints mentioned above.

Comment: Almost. But the extra rules and the (I hadn't know about it earlier) HttpMethodConstraint put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you'd need the following setup:

1.

```
/api/Item/344
{controller}/{id}
```

2.

```
/api/Item/Something/2334
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

and decorate the 'GetSomething' method as follows:

```
[ActionName("Something")]
public Item GetSomething(int id){}
```

3.

```
/api/Item?id=344
/api/Item/Something?id=2334
```

I'm not entirely sure about these - have you tried adding a default to the routes above:

```
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

4.

I'd expect `PUT` to just work if #3 is applied

Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: The catch here is that (like in the linked document) If you have a route that does not inlcude `{action}`, then WebApi Routing tries all public methods in the controller with matching primitive parameter types and/or any complex parameters.

Comment: @EricFalsken - I see now what you mean. I think a workaround would be to put a constraint on the `action` for the route `v{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`, so that only `Something` is allowed: `constraints = new {action = "Something"}`